Can we use <mat-error></mat-error> inside a *For* loop in Angular
I have created a common component. I am stuck in a problem where I am using angular material and using mat-form-field. I am using @if in angular 18 to check for a condition then mat-error is working fine. But when I am using @for it is not working and mat-error is showing inside input field not in mat-error. Also I need put my condition like this:
Above is the required format I am looking for. But I tried using single @if and @for as well. But @for is not working.
Here is the output when I am using @for:

First Image shows that error is coming inside a inputFor loop output when using with mat-error

@if(condition){
    @for(condition){
        <mat-error>{{error}}</mat-error>
    }
}

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label >{{label}}</mat-label>
            <input matInput [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': this.formGroup.get(controlName)?.invalid && this.formGroup.get(controlName)?.touched}" [formControlName]="controlName" (focus)="triggerValidation(controlName)" [required]="required" [type]="type" [placeholder]="placeholder">
                 @if(formGroup.get(controlName)?.invalid && formGroup.get(controlName)?.touched){
                     @for(error of getErrorMessages(controlName); track i; let i = $index){
                         <mat-error> {{ error }} </mat-error >
                      }
    }
    </mat-form-field>

I tried using ng-container. But for now ng-container is of no use as we have @if and @for block.
I am looking for below output using @if and @else:

Here is the output of my image:

Expected Output, currently I have used only @if so I am getting this output
Output which I am expecting

I don't know why you are doing @for for <mat-error>. You can just call getErrorMessages(controlName) within <mat-error>.
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
  <input matInput [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': this.formGroup.get(controlName)?.invalid && this.formGroup.get(controlName)?.touched}"
    [formControlName]="controlName" (focus)="triggerValidation(controlName)" [required]="required" 
    [type]="type" [placeholder]="placeholder">
  @if(formGroup.get(controlName)?.invalid && formGroup.get(controlName)?.touched){
    <mat-error> {{ getErrorMessages(controlName) }} </mat-error>
  }
</mat-form-field>


In your getErrorMessages() function make sure you are returning error messages if a control has an error or return '' if there is no error.

Thank You It worked for me.
Can you give me a brief what is the difference between both? For loop I was using and just the method with parameters?
Also can you suggest what can we implement if we really need @for inside @if?

@Tirthshah Ideally you would want to show one error message under a form control.
@if shows a content based on a condition. @for to repeat blocks of code like table rows, list of items.
By default, <mat-error> has some styles like other material tags. In your case, @if becomes true when the form control is invalid then the @for renders the <mat-error> for each error messages.
Errors like required and min length can get triggered at the same time thus rendering two error messages which affect the styles and messages gets pushed to the top towards the input.

I think this is a bug, so I raised the same on github:
MAT INPUT: The error messages show inside the form field, when a @if and @for are used to show the error messages. #30151
You can follow this bug to know more about this issue.

As a temporary workaround, you can simply use [hidden] to hide the errors and emulate the same behavior as the if condition.
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
    <input
      type="email"
      matInput
      [formControl]="emailFormControl"
      [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
      placeholder="Ex. pat@example.com"
    />
    @for(error of getErrorMessages(''); track i; let i = $index){
    <mat-error
      [hidden]="!(emailFormControl?.invalid && emailFormControl?.touched)"
    >
      {{ error }}
    </mat-error>
    }
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

Stackblitz Demo

Hello,
Actually I am not using [errorStateMatcher]. I tried using hidden but It did not worked.
Thank You for your response.
I am creating a reusable input component.

Give me some time I will modify it
